# Request for Feature Clarification for Apache Superset

Tags: visualization, apache-superset

I was looking for a visualization software for my project and came across Apache Superset. But I would like to clarify whether Apache superset supports role and user-based access to data visualization? Also can we use filters for each report as well? Any help will highly appreciated.

Thank you.